# Multiple sites in the same directory but separate database

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

In my Linux based shared hosting account with HostGator, it is soon going to be dozen of sites. There is files  count  limitation for CPanel backups in my account.

To reduce the total number of files I need suggestion from you all so that I continue to add new bunch of sites using Drupal-6.

I don't want to share the same database just to keep my maintenance simple. I know Drupal allows multiple sites in the same DB. But I want to avoid it.

**Can I reuse the same Drupal files in my old site and use them to create symbolic link from my new site?** Except for root/sites directory because it may contain temporary files or files used/uploaded specific to each site.

So if my Drupal 6 site  site1.com is there then I can reuse its files for my new site site2.com by creating symbolic links in site2.com pointing to sit1.com except for **sites** directory:

site2.com/includes->site1.com/includes

site2.com/modules-> site1.com/modules

site2.com/sites   ( not shared)

site2.com/misc -> site1.com/misc

....

I've gone through related thread: [Combining databases in Drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465247/combining-databases-in-drupal) but I don't want to go as per suggestions in it.

**Any suggestions about this idea?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is Drupal's multisite feature. This is intended to work separate database and uploaded files but with shared code across the sites. Basically you point the document root for each virtualhost at the same Drupal installation and Drupal takes care of loading the correct database.

Details here: http://drupal.org/getting-started/6/install/multi-site

Comment: Thanks, but this page is very confusing. I've a live site and I want to add a new site in the same files. This page talks about creating new all sites which I can't as there are plenty of setting/configuration I'd lose in installing the sites from scratch. I don't know but why this page lists only sub domain examples of single site instead of multiple sites

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue, I used this tutorial for drupal 6, Hope you'll benefit from it.

Tutorial: [Click Here](http://jamestombs.co.uk/2010-06-22/creating-a-drupal-multisite-enviroment-using-drupal-6/1135)